# Adding days to a date, then substracting specified days if it passes through them

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I was wondering if it was possible to add 7 days to a date and if it falls on a date I have specified before, it will substract the amount of dates it has fallen on. This is my try I can't seem to make work:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

days_to_add = 11
start = date(2020, 1, 1)
dates_to_skip = [(2020, 1, 6), (2020, 1, 7), (2020, 1, 14)]
days_skip = 0
x = 0

for days in days_to_add:
    while x < days_to_add:
        start += timedelta(days=1)
        x += 1

        if start == dates_to_skip:
            days_skip += 1

result = start - days_skip
print(str(result))
```

Comment: "I can't seem to make work" — what's wrong?

Comment: I gives me an error: value <int> not iterable. It has happened with all of my attempts, and the ones that didn't say this, didin't work at all.

Comment: OK, that means you need to use `for days in range(days_to_add):` to avoid it — as @Sergio Gracia says.

Comment: I gives a result, yet like if it hasn't skipped any days.

Comment: make all elements in `dates_to_skip` `date` objects. change for loop iterator to `range(days_to_add)`. change the conditional to `if start in dates_to_skip`. let me know if that gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slightly shorter: you could get rid of the `while` loop as follows

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = date(2020, 1, 1)
days_to_add = 11
dates_to_skip = [date(2020, 1, 6), date(2020, 1, 7), date(2020, 1, 14)]

skipped = 0
for days_add in range(days_to_add+1):
    if start + timedelta(days=days_add) in dates_to_skip:
        skipped += 1  

print(f"skipped {skipped} days between {start} and {start+timedelta(days=days_to_add)}.")
# skipped 2 days between 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-12.
```

A little bit of an outlook: `pandas` `date_range` could be useful here if you want to get into this:

```
import pandas as pd
# create a date range with all dates, including the ones to skip:
dr = pd.date_range(start, periods=days_to_add+1)
# select only the dates that are not in dates_to_skip:
dr = dr[~dr.isin(dates_to_skip)]
print(dr)
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04',
#                '2020-01-05', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10',
#                '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```